# jsonb_set not working as expected with nested collections, resulting in null value returned

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update a nested collection in my Postgres table using json_set, however, my approach is resulting in a collection of null values.

| id | payload | row_version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fbfd3b9d-bb20-4c1b-985f-0979890472ec | { "slots": [ { "bannerXCreatorSettings": { "additionalFields": [ { "label": "test-label", "enabled": true, "mandatory": false, "additionalFieldId": "label", "maxCharacterLimit": 22, "additionalFieldType": "TEXT", "colorHexOptionsList": [] }, { "label": "test-label-2", "enabled": true, "mandatory": false, "additionalFieldId": "label2", "maxCharacterLimit": 55, "additionalFieldType": "TEXT", "colorHexOptionsList": [] } ] } } ]} | 1 |

I have the following json payload stored in my table:

```json
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "bannerXCreatorSettings": {
        "additionalFields": [
          {
            "label": "test-label",
            "enabled": true,
            "mandatory": false,
            "additionalFieldId": "label",
            "maxCharacterLimit": 22,
            "additionalFieldType": "TEXT",
            "colorHexOptionsList": []
          },
          {
            "label": "test-label-2",
            "enabled": true,
            "mandatory": false,
            "additionalFieldId": "label2",
            "maxCharacterLimit": 55,
            "additionalFieldType": "TEXT",
            "colorHexOptionsList": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Within the `additionalFields` collections, I want to add `selectOptions`. Like this:

```json
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "bannerXCreatorSettings": {
        "additionalFields": [
          {
            "label": "test-label",
            "enabled": true,
            "mandatory": false,
            "additionalFieldId": "label",
            "maxCharacterLimit": 22,
            "additionalFieldType": "TEXT",
            "colorHexOptionsList": [],
            "selectOptions": [] <-- new field
          },
          {
            "label": "test-label-2",
            "enabled": true,
            "mandatory": false,
            "additionalFieldId": "label2",
            "maxCharacterLimit": 55,
            "additionalFieldType": "TEXT",
            "colorHexOptionsList": [],
            "selectOptions": [] <-- new field
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have written the following SQL to try update the JSON payload within my table:

```sql
select
    id,
    payload,
    row_version,
    jsonb_set(
        payload,
        '{slots}',
        (select
            jsonb_agg(
                jsonb_set(
                    slot_elem,
                     '{bannerXCreatorSettings}',
                    jsonb_set(
                        slot_elem -> 'bannerXCreatorSettings',
                        '{additionalFields}',
                        (
                           select
                              jsonb_agg(
                                jsonb_set(
                                   field_element,
                                   '{selectOptions}',
                                      jsonb_build_array()))
                                    from jsonb_array_elements(
                                        slot_elem -> '{bannerXCreatorSettings}' #>'{additionalFields}') WITH ORDINALITY a_t(field_element, idx_1))      
                                    )
                            )
                        )
                        FROM
                            jsonb_array_elements(
                                payload #> '{slots}') WITH ORDINALITY t(slot_elem, idx))) as payload_update
```

My understanding of SQL is limited, however, I feel as though this should work. Unfortunally the above query results in the following:

```json
{
  "slots": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your query doesn't reference any tables, so there is no place for the columns to come from:  `ERROR:  column "id" does not exist`

Comment: @jjanes I have updated my question to show all values in the row.

Comment: I mean the query itself.  All of the FROMs just have function calls, none of them include a table.  The function calls have no place to obtain their arguments.